# How to save a selection of drawings in MS-VISIO as pdf?

Tags: pdf, export, microsoft-visio, selection, save-as

I have a Visio file with a lot of drawings inside. I would like to export one drawing as pdf. How can I do that?

(P.S. Copying it to another Visio file is not helpful while I cannot save the object as PDF but the whole page - which never fits to my long thing diagram)

Comment: I don't have Visio to test, but if you install a PDF printer like CutePDF, are you able to print to that?  If you have Windows 10, there should be a built in option for PDF printing as well.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-visio-shapes-or-drawings-to-another-file-format-06372102-54e9-4ab6-b3f7-7ff6cfc6fd35

Comment: The problem is that in Visio I cannot save my selection as PDF. Saving a big PDF file and formatting it should be possible as I am currently try to find an alternative software. I can try what you suggested.

Comment: @Moab thanks for the comment. However, this is for just saving a visio file to PDF not just a selection of that. I need to have a selection and also do not have to save all the page size empty area.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in options can do this.

Make your selection, then **File** -> **Print**

select your PDF print option (I have 2 different ones, both work)

choose Print Selection

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. the problem is that if the figure is big, it splits it to different pages. I hardly can find a paper size which fits exactly like my figure. As an example, this is not a problem in other software such as powerpoint or coreldraw.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the drawing to a new Visio file and automatically resize the drawing page to fit the shapes on the new page by doing this:

1. On the Design tab, in the Page Setup group, click the Size button.
2. Click Fit to drawing.

   - The drawing page size changes to fit the drawing.

The reference is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-drawing-page-or-printer-paper-size-90ed5e3a-de76-410f-9aa2-045615cd8d6f).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1154190)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).